# Long click on button creates many instant clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Basically I'm trying to make a button to be performed again many times as long as the mouse is down on that button.

I need this for buttons with sliders. Right now, I click on a button for example "Increase Slider" and the slider is increased by 1 step, but now I want to be able to increase the slider many steps if I long press on that button.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please never use the phrase "it's not working" without the description of how exactly it's not working. Is it throwing an error? Which? Is it getting wrong results? Which? Is it going into an infinite loop? Crashing the browser? Setting the computer on fire? We already know it's not working; if it did, you wouldn't be posting here, you'd be happily working on the next challenge.

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/6x5j4ej2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `do` loop runs as many times as it can in 1000 ms, and the `mouseleave` and `mouseup` handlers never get a chance to run because [their events are sitting in the message queue](http://latentflip.com/loupe/) waiting for the `mousedown` handler to finish running through that loop.

The loop sets up a couple thousand timeouts, to be run at least 200 ms later. Those timeouts don't actually do anything given the code you posted, because [`window`'s `click` handler is being called, not your button's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#The_this_problem).

The `mouseleave` and `mouseup` handlers essentially do nothing, because `start` will be reset to a valid time before ever being checked.

## So how do we fix it?

There are two delays we want: the 1000 ms delay between the initial click and the first time the slider increases, and the 200 ms delay between slider increases. If the user cancels during the first 1000 ms, we'll count that as a single click. If the user cancels after the repetition starts, we shouldn't count that as a click. (We'll define "canceling" as releasing the mouse button or moving the cursor off the button. This means pressing the mouse button over the UI button and moving the cursor off will count as a click, but the code will be simpler.)

We can set up the delays by setting up a timeout that, after 1000 ms, sets up an interval that, every 200 ms, increases the slider. We won't be using the `click` event for the slider increase because of the last line of the spec:

> If the user cancels after the repetition starts, we shouldn't count that as a click.

So we'll give the slider-increase code its own function, `increaseSlider()` (which is good practice anyway):

```
function startLongClick (e) {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    increaseSlider();
    window.setInterval(() => {
      increaseSlider();
    }, 200);
  }, 1000);
}
$('#button').on('mousedown', startLongClick);
```

We put the first call to `increaseSlider()` in the timeout so the slider first increases 1000 ms after the initial click, not 1200. We use arrow functions in the timeout and interval because [arrow functions don't redefine `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this), so we'd be able to refer to the triggering `<button>` if necessary.

## [I can't stop it!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DX2yVucz24&t=6m50s)

As the code is now, a single click on the button will start the whole long-click process, with no way of stopping it. Stopping the process means stopping the timeout and interval, which we can do with `window.clearTimeout()` or `window.clearInterval()` (they're the same function; don't tell anybody). We'll need to hang on to the IDs `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` give us, and clear them in the `mouseup` and `mouseleave` handlers:

```
let intervalId;
let timeoutId;

function startLongClick (e) {
  timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
    increaseSlider();
    intervalId = window.setInterval(() => {
      increaseSlider();
    }, 200);
  }, 1000);
}

function cancelLongClick () {
  window.clearInterval(intervalId);
  window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}

$('#button').on('mousedown', startLongClick);
$('#button').on('mouseup', cancelLongClick);
$('#button').on('mouseleave', cancelLongClick);
```

## What about the short click?

Now the button's doing what we want it to do, with one exception: a short click doesn't do anything, because we're not using the `click` handler and the timeout is being cleared before `increaseSlider()` is ever called. A short click should be registered if a canceling event is fired after the `mousedown` event but before the timeout fires. Since `timeoutId` is undefined before the `mousedown` event and we don't need it once the timeout fires, we can assign `undefined` to it in the timeout and use it to determine whether we should register a short click:

```
let intervalId;
let timeoutId;

function startLongClick (e) {
  timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
    timeoutId = undefined;
    increaseSlider();
    intervalId = window.setInterval(() => {
      increaseSlider();
    }, 200);
  }, 1000);
}

function cancelLongClick () {
  window.clearInterval(intervalId);
  if (timeoutId) {
    increaseSlider();
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = undefined;
  }
}

$('#button').on('mousedown', startLongClick);
$('#button').on('mouseup', cancelLongClick);
$('#button').on('mouseleave', cancelLongClick);
```

We set `timeoutId` to `undefined` in the short-click code as well. Otherwise, after short-clicking, an increase would trigger every time you mouse out of the button.

## More buttons!

The code works now, but requires two global variables and is hard-coded for a specific button. Let's turn it into a general-purpose jQuery plugin*:

```js
(($) => {
  $.fn.repeatingClick = function (callback, delay = 500, interval = 200) {
    return this.each(function () {
      let intervalId;
      let timeoutId;
      function startLongClick (e) {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
          timeoutId = undefined;
          callback.call($(this), e);
          intervalId = window.setInterval(() => {
            callback.call(this, e);
          }, interval);
        }, delay);
      }
      function cancelLongClick (e) {
        window.clearInterval(intervalId);
        if (timeoutId) {
          callback.call(this, e);
          window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
          timeoutId = undefined;
        }
      }
      $(this).on('mousedown', startLongClick);
      $(this).on('mouseup', cancelLongClick);
      $(this).on('mouseleave', cancelLongClick);
    });
  }
})(jQuery);

function modifySlider (e) {
  let modifier = Number($(this).data('change'));
  $('progress').attr('value', Number($('progress').attr('value')) + modifier);
}

$('button').repeatingClick(modifySlider);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="dec" data-change="-1">&minus;</button>
<progress value="25" max="50"></progress>
<button id="inc" data-change="1">+</button>
```

What's changed?

- Replaced calls to `increaseSlider()` with a `callback` parameter and `callback.call($(this), e)`. This way, any function can be used as the callback, and since we used arrow functions in the timeout, we're able to use [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) with `this` to access the triggering element in the callback.
- Parameterized the delays in the timeout and interval into `delay` and `interval`, for more general use.
- Stuck the whole thing in a new jQuery function, `$.repeatingClick()`. Since jQuery objects can represent collections as well as individual elements, we wrap the original code in a call to `$.each()` to access each element individually. We also return the jQuery object in the usual style.

The rest is specific to this application: two buttons to modify the value of a (`<progress>`) 'slider', using custom `data-` attributes for the actual amounts so we can give both the same code.

<sup>*I've never written a jQuery plugin before; most of the code surrounding the core logic came straight from [jquery-longpress](https://github.com/vaidik/jquery-longpress/blob/master/jquery.longpress.js), a jQuery plugin that does almost what OP wants.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try using intervals instead of manually calculating time. Check this out:

```js
var value = 0
var addval;
var press = false;

$('#button').on('mousedown', function (e) {
 press = true;
 increaseValue();
 return false;
});


$('#button').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    clearInterval(addval);
 return false;
});

$('#button').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
 if (press)
  increaseValue();
});

$('#button').on('mouseup', function (e) {
 press = false;
    clearInterval(addval);
 return false;
});

function increaseValue() {
 addval = setInterval(function(){
  value++;
  $("#counter").text(value);
 }, 100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Press me</button>
<div id="counter">0</div>
```

You can adjust the speed by changing interval time.